# Not able to connect x64bit process to 32bit thread

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, eclipse-rcp, rmi

I am working on an Eclipse application developed using Eclipse RCP. This application runs on 32bit JVM on a x64bit machine.

Now the application has some native DLLs compiled to run on x64 platform. So the running app calls a x64bit thread of Eclipse using x64bit JVM.

When I try to run the app, x64bit one is starting, I checked in the task mananger, but it's not able to connect to the 32bit thread. The error it says is application not found in the registry. I checked an it's mentioned in the config.ini file, the proper version of JVM is mentioned in launch.ini too.

Somewhere I read that the calling process (32bit) is not able to find on which port the x64 process is running. So they are not able to connect.

I know this is may be very vague, but would it be possible to figure something out from this please? Kindly suggest something.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't connect from a 32-bit process to a 64-bit library. That isn't possible with [WoW64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64).

Comment: Are you saying you are running a 32 bit JVM and a separate 64 bit JVM each running an RCP? You would to use some sort of inter-process communication such as sockets to talk between these.

Comment: Hi Greg, I have two different Eclipse.exes which uses the appropriate JVMs. I mention this in the launch.ini files. From the code of 32bit, I am building the x64bit process with ProcessBuilder and mentioning these.

Comment: Hi Elliot, I have extracted both (32, 64) the JVMs, and using launch.ini file I point Eclipse executable to use an appropriate version.

Comment: So you do have two completely separate JVMs in separate processes - how are you trying to communicate between them?

Comment: Hi Greg, yes I have separate JVMs. The communication happens with RMI port. The x64bit process should report on which port it is running, and the output stream reader of caller process reads this until RMI spec is found. It connects to the process as soon as the RMI port is found.

Comment: I'm not an RMI expert but no one is going to be able to help unless you show us how you are setting up RMI in both JVMs. [edit] your question and add more detail.